# Is there a fuzzy string match library for Haskell?

Tags: library, haskell

Is there a fuzzy string match library for Haskell? I mean similar to how `Ctrl+p` search works in Sublime Text.
[Here is a demo of how it works.](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mattyork/fuzzy/blob/master/examples/disney.html) ([Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy))

I'm thinking to implement this if there is nothing available, but want to ask around beforehand to reduce unnecessary code and effort duplication.

Comment: Since I haven't found what I was looking for, I've started to put it together: https://github.com/Wizek/fuzzy-match